# Автоматическое обновление RecyclerView с Loader и ContentProvider

Tags: android, contentprovider, android-loader

Я уже задавала [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763848/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-recyclerview-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5), как наполнять  recyclerView во фрагменте актуальными данными из базы данных. И как я поняла, лучше всего для этой цели использовать Loader в связке с ContentProvider'ом. Но по поводу Loader-а всё же возникают сомнения, точно ли всегда ли он может актуализировать данные в recyclerView?

> This is a common gap with loader implementations. Occasionally, we may
>   be in position to find out when the content changes. More often, we
>   are not, or the work to find out about content changes has to be
>   handled by a much larger subsystem, beyond a simple Loader subclass.

Comment: думаю для автообновления вам нужен адаптер с обсервером (как [этот](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59))/ Хотя в плане связки с контент провайдером я этот вопрос не изучал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не совсем правильно поняли использование компонента ContentProvider. Основная задача ContentProvider это предоставление данных из Вашего приложения внешним приложениям.Поэтому, как раз его использование для доступа к вашей БД и является более затратным, чем использование  SQLiteOpenHelper, CursorLoader и т.п. Из [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html):

> A content provider is only required if you need to share data between multiple applications. For example, the contacts data is used by multiple applications and must be stored in a content provider. If you don't need to share data amongst multiple applications you can use a database directly via SQLiteDatabase.

В тоже время, в рамках реализации (либо оптимизации) функционала связанного с обновлением данных следует обратить внимание на предлагаемую Google концепцию Android Architecture Components.